# Cannot re-assign a value to XSLT variable, or can I exit from for-each loop conditionally

Tags: c#, xslt, xpath

Cannot re-assign a value to XSLT variable, or can I exit from
 `<xsl:for-each` conditionally
my XML

```
<R>
  <A id="a">  
    <S id="a111">1</S>  
    <S id="a222">2</S>
    <S id="a333">3
      <S id="a3331">3.1</S>
      <S id="a3332">3.2</S>
      <S id="a3333">3.3</S>  
    </S>
    <S id="a444">4</S>
    <S id="a555">5</S>
    <S id="a666">6</S>
  </A>
  <A id="x">
    <S id="x111">1</S>
    <S id="x222">2</S>
    <S id="x333">3
      <S id="x3331">3.1</S>
      <S id="x3332">3.2</S>
      <S id="x3333">3.3</S>
    </S>
    <S id="x444">4</S>
    <S id="x555">5</S>
    <S id="x666">6</S>
  </A>
</R>
```

my XSLT

```
     <select id ="S"  name="SList">
     <option>
       <xsl:attribute name="value"></xsl:attribute> Please Select S 
     </option>
     <xsl:for-each select="A[id='x']//S">

       <xsl:if test="'x3333'= @id">
         <xsl:variable name="currentS" select="true()"/>
       </xsl:if>
       <xsl:if test="'x3333'!= @id">
         <xsl:variable name="currentS" select="false()"/>
       </xsl:if>

       <xsl:if test="@currentS = false()">
         <option>
           <xsl:if test="@id = 'x3333'">
             <xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute>
           </xsl:if>
           <xsl:attribute name="value">
             <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
           </xsl:attribute>              
           <xsl:value-of select="Text"/>
         </option>
       </xsl:if>
     </xsl:for-each>
```

I'm trying to create a drop down list and I need to include `S` items in the list. I am passing the current position (current `S`, in this example `x3333`) and current id of `A`. I want to get only list of `S` elements within most recent `A` element.

In this example, since my current `S` is `x3333` and id of `A` is `x` I need only `x111`,`x222`,`x333`,`x3331`,`x3332` to be in the list. That means I need to eliminate these

```
  <S id="x444">4</S>,
  <S id="x555">5</S>,
  <S id="x666">6</S>, nodes
```

from this code `<xsl:for-each select="A[id='x']//S">`

I'm getting the list of `S` elements in `A` where `id='x'`

Can someone suggest me a solution please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not really clear what you try to do.
Here some hints to you xslt:

**Wrong access of  attribute:** `<xsl:for-each select="A[id='x']//S">`
To test for attribute id use @id: `<xsl:for-each select="A[@id='x']//S">`
**You cant redefine a variable:**

```
<xsl:if test="'x3333'= @id">
        <xsl:variable name="currentS" select="true()"/>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="'x3333'!= @id">
     <xsl:variable name="currentS" select="false()"/>
</xsl:if>
```

The variable currentS is only defined in the scope of the xsl:if.
To set a variable value depending of attribute id try this:

```
        <xsl:variable name="currentS">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="@id = 'x3333'">
                    <xsl:text>true</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:text>false</xsl:text>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
```

**Wrong access of variable value:** `<xsl:if test="@currentS = false()">`
xslt variable access is done wint `$` prefix.

```
<xsl:if test="$currentS = 'false'">
```

According my interpretation of your xlst this may help:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:template match="R">

        <select id ="S"  name="SList">
            <option>
                <xsl:attribute name="value"></xsl:attribute> Please Select S
            </option>
            <xsl:for-each select="A[@id='x']//S">
                <xsl:variable name="currentS">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="preceding::S[@id = 'x3333']">
                        <xsl:text>true</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:text>false</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>

            </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:if test="$currentS = 'false'">
                    <option>
                        <xsl:if test="@id = 'x3333'">
                            <xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:attribute name="value">
                            <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(text())"/>
                    </option>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </select>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which generate following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<select id="S" name="SList">
    <option value="">
        Please Select S
    </option>
    <option value="x111">1</option>
    <option value="x222">2</option>
    <option value="x333">3</option>
    <option value="x3331">3.1</option>
    <option value="x3332">3.2</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="x3333">3.3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply @hr_117 ,, when I try to acces the variable using  this methos <xsl:if test="$currentS = 'false'"> it says "variable or parameter not defined or out of scope2 ???

Comment: Thank you @hr_117 .. yes this is very good and fit for my pourpose. Thank you

Comment: Hi @hr_117
There is a one littile problem,
When my current S is 'a333'
it gives me "a111","a222","a333","a3331","a3332","a3333"

or 

When my current S is 'x333'
it gives me "x111","x222","x333","x3331","x3332","x3333"

I'm trying to fix it and mean time if you find time please help.
Thak you

Comment: I'm still not sure what you try to do. Perhaps changing the xls:when to `xsl:when test="preceding::S[@id = 'x333'] | ancestor::S[@id = 'x333']"` may help

Answer (score 0):

One way to do what you want to do with variables in XSLT is to use the XPath if statement in your variable's select:

```
<xsl:variable name="currentS" select=" if (@id = 'x3333') then true() else false()"/>
```

The XPath if is very hand when trying to do a variable whose value should depend on a if-then construction. But this is only available in a XPath 2.0 processor and it looks like OP uses a 1.0 processor. This should work:

```
   <xsl:variable name="currentS" select="@id = 'x3333'"/>
```

Comment: problem is when I am trying to read the value  <xsl:if test="@currentS = false()"> ??

Comment: The other thing to note is that variables are scoped in XSLT, so your currentS variable's scope is only within your xsl:if. That is another reason to use the XPath if in the variable's select: you can easily broaden the scope of your variable.

Comment: That's because in XSLT "@" is short hand for the attribute axis. To reference a variable you use "$". So <xsl:if test="$currentS = false()"> should work for you

Comment: Thank you for the reply @SteveoDevo but XSLt sayas if() is unknown ??

Comment: Looks like you aren't using an XPath 2.0 processor. I've updated my answer.

Comment: This the first part of my XSLT file......................................<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"  exclude-result-prefixes="xsl fo xs fn" >
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>  I think I am using xPath 2.0 Thanks for the help.

Comment: That's odd. Because the first example works for me in an XSLT 2.0 file using Saxon 9.4.x.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure where Saxon 9.4.x is defined i my XSLT